# How efficient are push!() and append!() methods in Julia?

Tags: arrays, julia

On [this](http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.4/manual/noteworthy-differences/) page it says that methods `push!()` and `append!()` are very efficient.

My question is how exactly efficient they are?

Namely,

If one **knows** the size of the final array, is it still faster to preallocate the array or growing it incrementally using `append!()` / `push!()` would be just as efficient?

Now consider the case when one **does not know** the size of the final array. For example, merging multiple arrays into 1 big array (call it `A`).

Two ways to achieve this:

1. `append!()`-ing each array to `A`, whose size has not been preallocated.
2. First sum dimensions of each array to find the final size of the merged array `A`. Then preallocate `A` and copy over contents of each array.

Which one would be more efficient in this case?

Comment: No idea what julia-lang is, but you just can't do better than preallocating and copying. Because the memory should be allocated no matter what, and preallocating it is the best that you can do. Of course this applies in the context of a contigious array...

Comment: Would definitely recommend you to check Julia out, especially if you like Python.

Comment: check the performance tips: http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.4/manual/performance-tips/#pre-allocating-outputs

Comment: They don't say anything about `append!()` / `push!()`'s benchmark

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The answer to a question like this is usually: "it depends". For example, what size array are you trying to make? What is the element-type of the array?

But if you're just after a heuristic, why not run a simple speed test? For example, the following snippet:

```
function f1(N::Int)
    x = Array(Int, N)
    for n = 1:N
        x[n] = n
    end
    return(x)
end

function f2(N::Int)
    x = Array(Int, 0)
    for n = 1:N
        push!(x, n)
    end
    return(x)
end

f1(2)
f2(2)

N = 5000000000
@time f1(N)
@time f2(N)
```

suggests that using `push!` is about 6 times slower than pre-allocating. If you were using `append!` to add larger blocks with less steps, the multiplier would almost certainly be less.

When interpreting these numbers, resist the knee-jerk reaction of "What!? 6-times slower!?". This number needs to be placed in the context of how important array building is to your entire program/function/subroutine. For example, if array building comprises only 1% of the run-time of your routine (for most typical routines, array building would comprise *much* less than 1%), then if your routine runs for 100 seconds, 1 second is spent building arrays. Multiply that by 6 to get 6 seconds. 99 seconds + 6 seconds = 105 seconds. So, using `push!` instead of pre-allocating increases the runtime of your whole program by 5%. Unless you work in high-frequency trading, you're probably not going to care about that.

For myself, my usual rule is this: if I can pre-allocate easily, then I pre-allocate. But if `push!` makes the routine much easier to code, with lower possibility of introducing bugs, and less messing around trying to pre-determine the appropriate array size, then I use `push!` without a second thought.

Final note: if you want to actually look at the specifics of how `push!` works, you'll need to delve into the C routines, since the [julia source](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/master/base/array.jl) just wraps a `ccall`.

**UPDATE:** OP questioned in the comments the difference between `push!` and an operation like `array(end+1) = n` in MATLAB. I haven't coded in MATLAB recently, but I do keep a copy on my machine since the code for all my older papers is in MATLAB. My current version is R2014a. My understanding is that in this version of MATLAB, adding to the end of the array will re-allocate the *entire* array. In contrast, `push!` in Julia works, to the best of my knowledge, much like lists in `.NET`. The memory allocated to the vector is dynamically added in blocks as the size of the vector grows. This massively reduces the amount of re-allocation that needs to be performed, although my understanding is that some re-allocation is still necessary (I'm happy to be corrected on this point). So `push!` should work *much* faster than adding to an array in Matlab. So we can run the following MATLAB code:

```
N = 10000000;
tic
x = ones(N, 1);
for n = 1:N
    x(n) = n;
end
toc


N = 10000000;
tic
x = [];
for n = 1:N
    x(end+1) = n;
end
toc
```

I get:

```
Elapsed time is 0.407288 seconds.
Elapsed time is 1.802845 seconds.
```

So, about a 5-times slowdown. Given the extreme non-rigour applied in the timing methodology, one might be tempted to say this is equivalent to the Julia case. But wait, if we re-run the exercise in Julia with `N = 10000000`, the timings are 0.01 and 0.07 seconds. The sheer difference in the magnitude of these numbers to the MATLAB numbers makes me very nervous about making claims about what is actually happening under the hood, and whether it is legitimate to compare the 5-times slowdown in MATLAB to the 6-times slowdown in Julia. Basically, I'm now out of my depth. Maybe someone who knows more about what MATLAB actually does under the hood can offer more insight. Regarding Julia, I'm not much of a C-coder, so I doubt I'll get much insight from looking through the source (which is publicly available, unlike MATLAB).

Comment: That does not seem like "much more efficient" as they claim.
When I read this I got very excited thinking that they somehow came up with the different, more efficient approach to handling memory allocation / garbage collection then guys at MathWorks, but seems like the only reason that Julia's `append!()` / `push!()` methods are faster than it's MATLAB equivalent is due to Julia's speed in general.

Comment: Last time I coded in Matlab there was no equivalent to `push!` and `append!`. You had to re-allocate the entire vector if you wanted to grow it. Admittedly, this was a while ago. This was obviously *much* slower than `push!`. I can't really offer much commentary on any newer functionality Matlab might have in this regard. But I stand by my original assertion: for *most* practical problems, the 6 times multiplier in array construction will barely be noticeable.

Comment: To clarify, by MATLAB's equivalent of Julia's `push!()` I meant `array(end+1) = val`, I think support for such syntax existed in MATLAB for a while, and yes, it does indeed perform re-allocation, but what makes you think that `push!()` or `append!()` in Julia do not perform re-allocation? Isn't that the reason behind 6x overhead?

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a lot! Very helpfull.

Answer (score 13):

`push!` will always be slower than inserting into a pre-allocated array, if for no other reason than `push!` (1) inserts the element, just as when you do so manually, and (2) increments the length of the array. Two operations cannot be faster than one, when one is part of two.

However, as noted in other answers the gap is often not so large as to something to be concerned about. Internally (last time I checked the code), Julia uses a grow-by-a-factor-of-2 strategy, so that you only need `log2(N)` reallocations.

If you do know the size of the array in advance, you can eliminate reallocations by using `sizehint!`. As you can easily test for yourself, this does not eliminate the performance penalty relative to insertion into a preallocated array, but it can reduce it.

Comment: Strictly speaking, I don't think that `push!` inserts a new element "just as when you do so manually". I believe that C++ (and possibly Julia as well) stores a special pointer to the memory location just past the last element of each array, and `push!` writes directly into that memory location. On the other hand, inserting into a pre-initialized array via, say, `arr[5] = 1` takes the pointer to the first element of `arr` and adds 5 to get a pointer to the desired write location. So `push!` requires one fewer pointer arithmetic operation ...

Comment: ... This is of course extremely unlikely to overcome all overhead that `push!` has over manual insertion, but nevertheless it is logically possible for `push!` to be faster than manual insertion by performing fewer pointer arithmetic operations.

Comment: @tparker, try `@code_llvm` on `push!(a, x)` and on `store_at_end!(a, x) = (@inbounds a[end] = x; a)`.

Comment: I don't see the relevance of your `store_at_end!` function to the question. I agree that manually appending a new element to the *end* of a preallocated array is quicker than using `push!`, but the OP is asking about building up a preallocated array one element at at a time, so you would typically be writing to an element *not* at the end of the array, necessitating the use of pointer arithmetic, which was the whole point of my comment. You are correct that in the standard Julia implementation, preallocation is faster, but this isn't a logical necessity.