# (Julia 1.x) Increased allocations by initialising variables?

Tags: julia

A programme I am writing has a user-written file containing parameters which are to be read in and implemented within the code. Users should be able to comment their input file by delimiting them with a comment character (I have gone with "#", in convention with Julia) - in parsing the input file, the code will remove these comments. Whilst making minor optimisations to this parser, I noted that instantiating the second variable prior to calling `split()` made a noticeable difference to the number allocations:

```
function removecomments1(line::String; dlm::String="#")
    str::String = ""

    try
        str, tmp = split(line, dlm)
    catch
        str = line
    finally
        return str
    end
end


function removecomments2(line::String; dlm::String="#")
    str::String = ""
    tmp::SubString{String} = ""

    try
        str, tmp = split(line, dlm)
    catch
        str = line
    finally
        return str
    end
end

line = "Hello world # my comment"
@time removecomments1(line)
@time removecomments2(line)

$>  0.016092 seconds (27.31 k allocations: 1.367 MiB)
    0.016164 seconds (31.26 k allocations: 1.548 MiB)
```

My intuition (coming from a C++ background) tells me that initialising both variables should have resulted in an increase in speed as well as minimising further allocations, since the compiler has already been told that a second variable is required as well as its corresponding type, however this doesn't appear to hold. Why would this be the case?

Aside: Are there any more efficient ways of achieving the same result as these functions?

**EDIT**:
Following a post by Oscar Smith, initialising `str` as type `SubString{String}` instead of `String` has reduced the allocations by around 10%:

```
$>  0.014811 seconds (24.29 k allocations: 1.246 MiB)
    0.015045 seconds (28.25 k allocations: 1.433 MiB)
```

Comment: Before jumping to any conclusions, you should use BenchmarkTools and ensure that you're not benchmarking in global scope. `using BenchmarkTools; @btime removecomments1($line); @btime removecomments2($line)`.

Comment: I wasn't aware that benchmarking in the global scope would make a difference, but here are the results of using `@btime` instead of `@time`:
```249.887 ns (5 allocations: 224 bytes)```; ```262.174 ns (6 allocations: 256 bytes)```

Comment: Also, it looks like your `@time` calls captured the compilation time for your two functions. You should at least run the functions once before using `@time`. `removecomments1(line) == removecomments2(line)` would be a good line to run before using `@time`.

Comment: Pre-allocation is mainly used for arrays, not for strings or other scalars. As far as I know, there's no performance or memory advantage to pre-allocating a string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your example, the only reason you need the try-catch block is because you're trying to destructure the output of `split` even though `split` will return a one element array when the input line has no comments. If you simply extract the first element from the output of `split`, then you can avoid the try-catch construct, which will save you time and memory:

```
julia> using BenchmarkTools

julia> removecomments3(line::String; dlm::String = "#") = first(split(line, dlm))
removecomments3 (generic function with 1 method)

julia> @btime removecomments1($line);
  198.522 ns (5 allocations: 224 bytes)

julia> @btime removecomments2($line);
  208.507 ns (6 allocations: 256 bytes)

julia> @btime removecomments3($line);
  147.001 ns (4 allocations: 192 bytes)
```

In partial answer to your original question, pre-allocation is mainly used for arrays, not for strings or other scalars. For more discussion of when to use pre-allocation, check out [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34751225/how-efficient-are-push-and-append-methods-in-julia).

Comment: Blimey, that's a significant improvement, especially when the `catch` would usually come into effect! I haven't come across `first()` before and search engines only appear to show it in use [here](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/interfaces/index.html#extending-in-place-broadcast-1) and [here](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/iterators/index.html#Base.Iterators.zip). Even searching the [official documentation](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/search/?q=first%28%29) doesn't show anything - what is it and what does it do?

Comment: `first` is a generic function that extracts the first element of a collection. It has methods in various packages that extend its functionality. [Here's the docs for the implementation in Base.](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/collections/#Base.first)

Answer (score 0):

To reason about what this is doing, think about what the split function would return if it was written in c++. It would not be copying, but would instead return a `char*`. As such, all that `str::String = ""` is doing is making Julia create an extra string object to ignore.

Comment: This initialisation is present in both functions, so surely it wouldn't make a difference in allocations?

Either way, if `str::String = ""` is not used by either function then I should probably change that part of the code, however completely removing the initialisation throws `LoadError: UndefVarError: str not defined`. Instead initialising it with the type `SubString{String}` has reduced the allocations, but is this somehow still superfluous to requirement?