# Why is this task faster in Python than Julia?

Tags: python, r, performance, julia

I ran the following code in RStudio:

```
exo <- read.csv('exoplanets.csv',TRUE,",")
df <- data.frame(exo)

ranks <- 570
files <- 3198
datas <- vector()

for ( w in 2:files ) {
    listas <-vector()
    for ( i in 1:ranks) {
            name <- as.character(df[i,w])
            listas <- append (listas, name)
    }
    datas <- append (datas, listas)
}
```

It reads a huge NASA CSV file, converts it to a dataframe,
converts each element to string, and adds them to a vector.

RStudio took 4 min and 15 seconds.

So I decided to implement the same code in Julia.
I ran the following in VS Code:

```
using CSV, DataFrames

df = CSV.read("exoplanets.csv", DataFrame)

fil, col = 570, 3198
arr = []

for i in 2:fil
        for j in 1:col
            push!(arr, string(df[i, j]))
        end
end
```

The result was good.
The Julia code took only 1 minute and 25 seconds!

Then for pure curiosity I implemented the same code
this time in Python to compare.
I ran the following in VS Code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

exo = pd.read_csv("exoplanets.csv")
arr = np.array(exo)

fil, col = 570, 3198
lis = []

for i in range(1, fil):
        for j in range(col):
            lis.append(arr[i][j].astype('str'))
```

The result shocked me! Only 35 seconds!!!
And in Spyder from Anaconda only 26 seconds!!!
Almost 2 million floats!!!
Is Julia slower than Python in data analysis?
Can I improve the Julia code?

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34755370/11659881) seems helpful. I would try preallocating all of the space that you need for the array in Julia and in Python (rather than using `push` and `append`) and see how they compare then.

Comment: I would suggest reading through https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/performance-tips/ (especially the first couple of sections that talk about `global` variables and "Avoid containers with abstract type parameters").

Also, please post a link to `exoplanets.csv` so that people can run your code.

Comment: I'm pretty sure declaring `arr = []` as vector of Strings would get you miles ahead. But Bogumil's answer is even better.

Comment: How many threads are available to julia?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**NOTE:** I wrote the below assuming you want the other column order (as in the Python and R examples).  It is more efficient in Julia this way; to make it work equivalently to your original behaviour, permute the logic or your data at the right places (left as an exercise). Bogumił's anwer does the right thing already.

---

Put stuff into functions, preallocate where possible, iterate in stride order, use views, and use builtin functions and broadcasting:

```
function tostringvector(d)
    r, c = size(d)
    result = Vector{String}(undef, r*c)
    v = reshape(result, r, c)
    for (rcol, dcol) in zip(eachcol(v), eachcol(d))
        @inbounds rcol .= string.(dcol)
    end
    return result
end
```

Which certainly can be optimized harder.

Or shorter, making use of what `DataFrames` already provides:

```
tostringvector(d) = vec(Matrix(string.(d)))
```

Comment: In the OP question the data should be collected in rows (this is what is done in the DataFrames.jl variant) not in columns (it is collected in columns in R/Python variant of the code). Your excellent answer shows the difference - your code will be faster than mine because you go columnwise not rowwise.

Comment: Damn column orders! :D I should have wondered harder why you used `reduce(vcat,..)`.

Comment: It seems that the slow step is because of CSV + DataFrame job. Pandas is just too fast (written in C?) Overall results: 1m 18s
 using CSV, DataFrames

 df = CSV.read("exoplanets.csv", DataFrame)
 arr = vec(Matrix(string.(df)))



1m 18s
 using CSV, DataFrames
 df = CSV.read("exoplanets.csv", DataFrame)

 function tostringvector(d)
      r, c = size(d)
      result = Vector{String}(undef, r*c)
      v = reshape(result, r, c)
      for (rcol, dcol) in zip(eachcol(v), eachcol(d))
          @inbounds rcol .= string.(dcol)
      end
      return result
 end

Comment: 1m 31s:
 using CSV, DataFrames
 df = CSV.read("exoplanets.csv", DataFrame)
 arr = reduce(vcat, eachrow(Matrix(string.(df[2:570, 1:3198]))))   THANKS A LOT FOR THE HELP

Comment: You mean that `CSV.read("exoplanets.csv", DataFrame)` is slow? The reason is compilation cost most likely. If you have homogenous data and want to avoid paying compilation cost use `DelimitedFiles` module. After compilation CSV is faster than pandas, especially for large data, see https://juliacomputing.com/blog/2020/06/fast-csv/. Note that compilation is one time cost (when you run the code again it should run faster)

Comment: I knew about compilation issue, but could not make it work anyway. Every time i ran the code the time is about 85s to Julia vs 35s to python. Then I decided to trick vscode: I imported modules once for both languages, but doubled the task of read csv>convert dataframe>for iterate>convert string>add to array. Now python went from 35s to 66s, so took 31s to double the task. Julia went from 85s to 93s!!! Julia took 8s to double the task!!! thats insane. Now is clear that Julia is a beast if you know how to use. THANKS EVERYONE!!!

Comment: [Quantinsti](https://blog.quantinsti.com/julia-programming/) has some good tests for Multiple operations on large datasets. 100 groups of ~10,000,000 rows, Python (pandas package) and R (dplyr package) resulted in an internal error and out of memory error, respectively while Julia took 2.4 seconds the first time and 1.8 seconds the second time. Original [source](https://h2oai.github.io/db-benchmark/).

Comment: also in about 2 weeks, Julia should be about 10 seconds faster here. there was some improvements to precompilation that significantly improve csv's startup time.

Answer (score 10):

It depends on what you want to test (i.e. if you want to test looping or just want the result fast). I assume you want the result fast and in a clean code, in which case I would write this operation in the following way in Julia:

```
arr = reduce(vcat, eachrow(Matrix(string.(df[2:570, 1:3198]))))
```

can you please confirm that this produces the expected result and what is the timing of this operation?
(in this I assume that you have more rows than 570 and more columns than 3198 so I subset them first)

If you want to test loops then the comments under your answer would start to be relevant.

Also note that your code for DataFrames.jl does not perform the same operation as codes in R and Python (looping order is different so could you please double check what you need). This difference is crucial for performance. I have given you the code reproducing the behavior of your DataFrames.jl code (which is a harder/slower variant of what you want to do in comparison to R/Python codes)

Comment: Your answer is very instructive but a bit slower, thanks a lot.

Comment: Yes - it is slower, because it does a different operation than what @phipsgabler's solution does. In my answer I reproduce your Julia code. phipsgabler reproduced Python code. Out of couriosity - what was the speed of phipsgabler's solution on your data (to have a comparison)?

Answer (score 5):

Given your comment to the @phipsgabler answer, what you are timing here is the fixed costs of importing the modules and compile more than the task itself..