# append! Vs push! in Julia

Tags: julia

In Julia, you can permanently append elements to an existing vector using `append!` or `push!`. For example:

```
julia> vec = [1,2,3]
3-element Vector{Int64}:
 1
 2
 3

julia> push!(vec, 4,5)
5-element Vector{Int64}:
 1
 2
 3
 4
 5

# or

julia> append!(vec, 4,5)
7-element Vector{Int64}:
 1
 2
 3
 4
 5
```

But, what is the difference between `append!` and `push!`? [According to the official doc](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/collections/#Base.append!) it's recommended to:

> *"Use push! to add individual items to a collection which are not already themselves in another collection. The result
> of the preceding example is equivalent to push!([1, 2, 3], 4, 5, 6)."*

So this is the main difference between these two functions! But, in the example above, I appended individual elements to an existing vector using `append!`. So why do they recommend using `push!` in these cases?

Comment: related with the https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34751225/how-efficient-are-push-and-append-methods-in-julia

Comment: @jbytecode, yes, but not the answer to my question! I asked *"why do they recommend using push! in these cases?"*

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`append!(v, x)` will iterate `x`, and essentially `push!` the elements of `x` to `v`. `push!(v, x)` will take `x` as a whole and add it at the end of `v`. In your example there is no difference, since in Julia you can iterate a number (it behaves like an iterator with length 1). Here is a better example illustrating the difference:

```
julia> v = Any[]; # Intentionally using Any just to show the difference

julia> x = [1, 2, 3]; y = [4, 5, 6];

julia> push!(v, x, y);

julia> append!(v, x, y);

julia> v
8-element Vector{Any}:
  [1, 2, 3]
  [4, 5, 6]
 1
 2
 3
 4
 5
 6
```

In this example, when using `push!`, `x` and `y` becomes elements of `v`, but when using `append!` the *elements* of `x` and `y` become elements of `v`.

Comment: Official doc says *"Use push! to add individual items to a collection which are not already themselves in another collection."* this means it's recommended to use `push!` instead of `append!` in that situation! This is why I intentionally provided those examples to show in those situations, `append!` works as well! But why are they recommended to use `push!`? After all, I got your point! Thank you so much!

Comment: @fredrikekre please add a comment about untyped containers as otherwise other will use your code to learn Julia and complain how slow it is ;)

Comment: Sure, I updated the example.

Comment: So essentially append flattens x and y before adding them to a scalar list v

Answer (score -4):

Since Julia is still in its early phase it'd be best if you follow the community standards, and one of the community standards, is your code making "sense" to other developers at first sight - I should know what your "intents" are immediately I read your code.

About append!, the doc says:

> "For an ordered container collection, add the elements of each
> collections to the end of it. !!! compat "Julia 1.6" Specifying
> multiple collections to be appended requires at least Julia 1.6."

The append! method was added and requires Julia 1.6 to use for multiple collections; so in a sense it is the method that's going to be used in the future as Julia gets adopted a lot, Python uses it too, so adopters from there would likely use it too.

About push!, the doc says:

> "Insert one or more items in collection. If collection is an ordered
> container, the items are inserted at the end (in the given order). If
> collection is ordered, use append! to add all the elements of another
> collection to it."

**The doc advises you use "append!" over "push!" when your collection is ordered. So as a Julia user, if I see append! on your code, I should know the collections its making changes on is in some way "ordered". That's just it. Otherwise, push! and append! does same things(something that might change in the future), but please follow community standards, it will help.**

So use append! when you care about order and use push! when order doesn't matter in your collections. This way, any Julia user reading your code, will know your intents right away; but please don't mix them up

Comment: wait, there are some issues in this answer... `append!` and `push!` exist well before Julia 1.6, and the order has nothing to do. In case of collections, `append!` adds the elements of the collection, `push!` adds the collection as a whole, that's all..